# no such file to load -- nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I have followed this instructions (for Macosx):
http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

GemFile

```
gem 'nokogiri'
```

Controller's code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
```

I use Rails 3.1.3

```
LoadError in ScriptsController#tv2db

no such file to load -- nokogiri
```

If i use "irb", it's ok

```
>> require 'nokogiri'
=> true
```

Comment: do you have `gem 'nokogiri'` in your Gemfile ?

Comment: yes, and i've alredy run "bundle install"

Comment: RESOLVED deleting Gemfile.lock and re-run "Bundle install"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't forget to restart server.

Comment: i've deteled Gemfile.lock and re-run "Bundle install". It works!